# Compare the three columns and replace the unique string with the string in the remaining columns. Python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe contains multiple columns among them three columns are related to gender.

df =

```
gen_1    gen_2    gen_3

M          M        M
F          M        M
F          F        F
F          F        M
F          M        F
```

The data is taken from 3 different periods.

```
np.where(df['gen_1'] == df['gen_2']).replace(df['gen_2'])
```

But I need an output

```
gen_1    gen_2    gen_3    Gender

M          M        M         M
F          M        M         M
F          F        F         F
F          F        M         F 
F          M        F         F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need value with most counts, mode per `axis=1` by [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html):

```
cols = ['gen_1','gen_2','gen_3']
df['Gender'] = df[cols].mode(axis=1)
print (df)
  gen_1 gen_2 gen_3 Gender
0     M     M     M      M
1     F     M     M      M
2     F     F     F      F
3     F     F     M      F
4     F     M     F      F
```

Comment: The df contains many other columns. we need to select specific columns and create a new column.

Comment: If your df has more columns than just gen_1,gen_2,gen_3 then the above code should just add the Gender column to it!